# Codeigniter not getting rendered

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wont to develop, a CodeIgniter app that it works on a live server but has a problem to work on localhost
................
I change the config 
and it works but it can not render pages
I hope u can help me.
my `.htaccess`

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /sma/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|install|update)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For godady Shared Hosting Server uncomment the line below
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

# Please comment this if you have uncommented the above
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [NC,L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not getting rendered? What kind of errors are you getting? What do your logs say?

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL /poss/login was not found on this server.

Comment: Is your base URL well defined in CI's `config.php`?

Comment: Are you sure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled? Also, you need to comment the line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [NC,L,QSA]` and uncomment `# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`